# tomcat 9.0 SSL Configuration

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I am using tomcat 9 and trying to configure SSL.
STEP1 : Created a tomcat.jks certificate  using the command keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore tomcat.jks and stored in%CATALINA_HOME%\ssl location.

STEP2. in server.xml, add below:

```
<Connector port="8443" 
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service="HTTP/1.1" 
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        sslEnabled="true"
        scheme="https" 
        certificateKeystoreFile="ssl/tomcat.jks"
        certificateKeystorePassword="tomcat"
        clientAuth="false"
        sslProtocol="TLS">
    </Connector>
```

While launching https://localhost:8443 getting the error as Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED . Any settings i am missing. Please help.

Comment: Working now, Enable the flag chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Answer (score 0):

https://**localhost**:8443  - try using one of the valid cert URLs - the problem is you don't have localhost as a valid cert DNS name in the jks file (and shouldn't)

Answer (score -1):

chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
Enabled the flag

Comment: The question was not about how to degrade security but to correct a configuration problem on server side

Answer (score -1):

For applications that do not require an SSL certificate or which doesn't have one, either a `self hosted website` or an application deployed locally, Chrome allows disabling the warning about https certificates if the address is localhost. Do the following:

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Enter the below into the address bar in Chrome.
   `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`
3. Set the option to `enabled` on *allow-insecure-localhost*

Comment: The question was not about how to degrade security but to correct a configuration problem on server side